# Tor browser error after editing torrc file for Hidden Service OSX

Tags: configuration, onion-services, mac, error

```
#HiddenServiceDir /opt/local/var/lib/tor/hidden_service/
#HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
```

I get an error like this:

> Tor unexpectedly exited. This might be due to a bug in Tor itself, another program on your system, or faulty hardware. Until you restart Tor, the Tor Browser will not able to reach any websites. If the problem persists, please send a copy of your Tor Log to the support team. Restarting Tor will not close your browser tabs.

So I opened terminal and tried to verify and got this message:

```
tor --verify-config
Jun 09 11:31:29.100 [notice] Tor v0.2.7.6 running on Darwin with Libevent 2.0.22-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.2h and Zlib 1.2.8.
Jun 09 11:31:29.101 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Jun 09 11:31:29.102 [notice] Configuration file "/opt/local/etc/tor/torrc" not present, using reasonable defaults.
Configuration was valid
```

When I make any changes in the torrc file, this problem occurs. When I delete them the problem disappears. What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I had the sample problem, and solution for me was to tighten the permission of HiddenServiceDir location. Make it drwx------ fixed the issue.
I was getting the warning that Permissions on directory /user/xx/hiddenServiceDir/ are too permissive.. failed to parse/validate config: Failed to configure rendezvous options. See logs for details.

Comment: for windows see https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/16015/17207

Answer (score 1):

In another question you try to find the `torrc` for Tor Browser, if this is being run in a Tor Browser context then the directory likely won't exist and the tor process itself (running as your user) wont have the privileges to create it.

You should instead use a directory path that your own user could create/control instead of `/opt/local/`, second of all if, as it appears your `torrc` is not in the default location (determined at compile time) of `/opt/local/etc/tor/torrc`, you should run `tor --verify-config -f /path/to/your/own/torrc` to check it and `tor -f /path/to/your/own/torrc` to run it.

However this isn't an ideal solution, you should prefer to run the tor process under it's own low-privileged account as a system service. You should try following the Tor Project's instructions for [installing up Tor on Mac OS X](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-osx.html.en).